# How can I trim silence at the start and end of a recording(wav) in python?

Tags: python, pyaudio, audio-processing, wave

I am trying to remove the silence at the start and end of this recording, so that I just have the voice in between, no need to remove any silence in between, just the start and end portions of the audio file.

[Amplitude vs. Time Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZOer.png)

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


filename = "my_recd.wav"

# Load the saved audio file for plotting
waveform = wave.open(filename, "rb")
signal = waveform.readframes(-1)
signal = np.frombuffer(signal, dtype=np.int16)

time = np.linspace(0, len(signal) / 44100, num=len(signal))

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.plot(time, signal, color='blue', label='Audio Waveform')
plt.title("Audio Waveform")
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I first tried to locate the point after which audio starts exceeding the threshold, in this case,after trying a moving-averages with a threshold of 1100 and window-size 100, I was able to locate the starting for this audio and tried to apply that on a reversed array but that failed, so I am looking forward to a solution where I do not have to hardcode the threshold values.
Just not willing to incorporate any speech recognition libraries into this. I want a minimalistic solution which solves this problem.

Comment: Do you think you could explain more as to what or why it failed on the reversed array? Did it truncate too much, or not enough, or something else?

Comment: It did not truncate anything, or something just went wrong. I am trying to find a solution where I do not have to hardcode a threshold value, and under the assumption that we have some silence at the start and end of a recording and the recordings are less than a minute, is there any property of a recording which we could target to get the starting and ending index of a trimmed portion which helps us get rid of the starting and trailing silences.

Comment: I think it is finally solved, forgot to mention it. It was resolved by making a function to find the mean dBFS for that wav file and then applying a filter by starting from start and end of the wav file seperately.